# individual license to volume license

Tags: licensing, disk-volume

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

My company has about 100 computer each using individual licenses for Microsoft Office and Windows. We are looking to upgrade about 50 computers. We, in the past, have used Dell as our main supplier of PCs and would like to continue with them.

What would be the best route for us in upgrading these 50 computers. We were thinking volume licensing for quicker setup and configuration.

My Question is: Can we get our hardware though Dell with volume licenses? or does the hardware/software purchases need to be done separately?

Comment: I agree - not quite sure of your question but I agree - volume licencing makes a lot of sesne.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We purchase both our hardware and software through Dell and they have always told us we have to purchase the system with the basic non-VL Windows license and then "upgrade" to a volume license. Obviously with MS Office, you can just purchase a system without Office and then only purchase the VL version.

When we buy, we buy individual computers one at a time. If you were buying in bulk, they might have other options.